# Declaration vs. Prototype vs. Symbol vs. Definition vs. Implementation

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

I see the terms "declaration," "prototype" and "symbol" thrown around interchangeably a lot when it comes to code like the following:

```
void MyUndefinedFunction();
```

The same goes for "definition" and "implementation" for things like this:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod()
{
    // Actual code here.
}
```

Are there any distinctions between the terms, as with "argument" and "parameter?"  Or are they truly synonymous?

Note: I'm not sure if this belongs here or on Programmers, so I [posted it on both sites.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72896/declaration-vs-prototype-vs-symbol-vs-definition-vs-implementation)  If anyone has any objections, let me know and I'll delete one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you run into a purist, they are generally interchangable, except for symbol and prototype (difficult to give absolutes on [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic))

- **symbol** generally refers to a hook point for linking 2 bits of code together, such as a library entry point, or a target for resolving static linking
- **prototype** generally refers to a definition of what a function/method looks like (arguments, return type, name, various types of visibility), but doesn't include an implementation.

You missed function vs. method, but my definition is:

- **function** a callable bit of code that isn't bound to an object
- **method** a callable bit of code in an object's namespace. Generally implemented by the compiler as a function that takes the object instance as it's first argument.

Possibly parameter hints at limiting scope, and therefore read-only.

**Note** If you ask a purist, you're more likely to have an *argument* than a *parameter*.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between declaration and prototype is mainly in C, where the following is a non-prototype declaration:

```
int foo();
```

Note that this is different from:

```
int foo(void);
```

The latter is a prototype for a function taking no arguments, while the former is a declaration for a function whose argument types are not specified in the declaration. This can actually be useful to avoid function-pointer-type casts with certain uses of function pointers, but it's very easy to mess up, and messing it up invokes undefined behavior. Many C programmers consider non-prototype declarations harmful, and gcc has a warning option to flag them.